# Changing the syntax highlighting color in a Rmarkdown/beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, rmarkdown

Which tex package does Rmarkdown use by default to implement syntax highlighting and how to change the highlighting colors?

I have written a style file which i use as a template for my beamer presentations written in Rmarkdown.

When I include a code chunk, e.g:

```
g = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=cyl, size=cyl)) +
      geom_point() +
      theme(legend.position="none")
```

This is visible in the knitted pdf as a code chunk as it apparently draws on some RMD defaults not specified in my style file.

By adding the following to the style file, I was able to change the background color of the code chunk and the font size:

```
\let\oldShaded\Shaded
\let\endoldShaded\endShaded
\renewenvironment{Shaded}{\footnotesize\oldShaded}{\endoldShaded}

\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{      221,    219,    217}
```

Now I would also like to change the syntax highlighting color to better match the overall style of my template.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please also read the [welcome guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and provide a MWE. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857212/incorporate-code-listings-from-an-external-file-in-knitr-markdown ?

Comment: Hi, this question aims at incorporating code chunks from other languages (stan, python, etc.) in Rmd which is unfortunately not what I am looking for (I want to change the color of r syntax highlighting which must be somehow supplied by some default/hidden Rmarkdown/latex style file). A minimal working example is difficult to provide. One could open a default beamer template in rstudio and try to change the color of the code chunks. But to do this, one has to know what is the default latex environment/package given by rmarkdown to highlight syntax - which is precisely what im looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[image: mwe]

````
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    highlight: espresso
---

# foo

```{r,eval=FALSE}
g = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, 
      color=cyl, size=cyl)) +
      geom_point() +
      theme(legend.position="none")
```

For more styles: `pandoc --list-highlight-styles`
````